# Nginx exclude directory from rule

Tags: nginx, rewrite, cache

I try to exclude 2 directories from my cache rule in nginx.

So I got this cache rule, that works great.

```
location ~* .(js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|pdf|ppt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|ico|flv|txt|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
    etag on;
    if_modified_since exact;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
}
```

The problem with this rule is, that its set the header for every jpg and png file and the cms can't generate publices images from my master images.

So I want/try to exclude the 2 dierctories from the rule, but I cant get it work.

```
location ~ ^/(out/pictures/generated/product/|out/pictures/master/product)/ {
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, max-age=0";
}

location ~* .(js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|pdf|ppt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|ico|flv|txt|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
    etag on;
    if_modified_since exact;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
}
```

But it dont work. If I just leave this rule active, it works.

```
location ~ ^/(out/pictures/generated/product/|out/pictures/master/product)/ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, max-age=0";
    }
```

So it seems that the "no-cache" rule is always overwritten by the file types rule?! How can I get to my goal?

Comment: One of the directories will not match as your rule for it ends with two `/`s

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figure it out. This works for me:

```
location ~ ^/(out/pictures/generated/product/|out/pictures/master/product)/ {
    location ~* .(js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|pdf|ppt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|ico|flv|txt|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
      etag on;
      if_modified_since exact;
      add_header Pragma "public";
      add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, max-age=0";
}
```